# How to define variables by list droping extra parts?

Tags: scala

This is working fine,

```
 val Array(a,b) = "Hello,Bye".split(',')
```

But it is an error because extra-information is not ignored:

```
 val Array(a,b) = "Hello,Bye,etc".split(',')
 // scala.MatchError: ...
```

how to ignore extra-information?

---

Same error in the case of less items:

```
 val Array(a,b) = "Hello".split(',')
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: no elegant way like the Javascript [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Answer (score 3):

Add a placeholder using underscore:

```
val Array(a,b, _) = "Hello,Bye,etc".split(',')
```

---

**EDIT**: Using `match-case` syntax is generally more preferred and more flexible (and you can catch all possible outcome):

```
val s = "Hello,Bye,etc"

s.split(',') match {
  case Array(a) => //...
  case Array(a, b) => //...
  case Array(a, b, rest@_*) => //...
  case _ => //Catch all case to avoid MatchError
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@_` will cover both instances.

```
val Array(a,b,x@_*) = "Hello,Bye,etc".split(',')
//a: String = Hello
//b: String = Bye
//x: Seq[String] = ArraySeq(etc)

val Array(c,d,z@_*) = "Hello,Bye".split(',')
//c: String = Hello
//d: String = Bye
//z: Seq[String] = ArraySeq()
```

---

From your comments it looks like you want to default to `""`, an empty `String`. I found a way to do it with `Stream`, which has been deprecated in Scala 2.13, but so far it is the cleanest solution I've found.

```
val Stream(a,b,c,d,_*) = "one,two,etc".split(",").toStream ++ Stream.continually("")
//a: String = one
//b: String = two
//c: String = etc
//d: String = ""
```

Comment: `val Array(x, y, _*) = "a b" split " "` for 2 or more, no side-effects, `a` and `b`  are Strings... But `y@_*` will be a Vector in the case of multiple itens,   `val Array(x, y@_*) = "a b c d e" split " "`... So, seems no analog of Javascript's [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making the result values of type `Option[String]` by `lift`-ing the split `Array[String]` (viewed as a partial function) into an `Int => Option[String]` function:

```
val opts = "Hello".split(",").lift
// opts: Int => Option[String] = <function1>

opts(0)
// res1: Option[String] = Some(Hello)

opts(1)
// res2: Option[String] = None
```

Or, if `String` values are preferred with `None` translated to `""`:

```
val strs = "Hello,world".split(",").lift.andThen(_.getOrElse(""))
// strs: Int => String = scala.Function1$$Lambda$...

strs(0)
// res3: String = Hello

strs(1)
// res4: String = "world"

strs(2)
// res5: String = ""
```

Note that with this approach, you can take as many `opts(i)` or `strs(i)`, i = 0, 1, 2, ..., as wanted.

Comment: Useful for *templates*, `println(s"${opts(0)} - ${opts(1)}")`, no risk of error messages... But ideal behaviour (as in [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io), Javascript template literals/Destructuring assignment, etc.) is to use empty string instead message "None". There are a easy way to configure empty in `lift`?

Comment: Oops, the `Some()` is tampering with the string content, it is ugly... About `.getOrElse("")` is a solution, is like a filter... But, if there are no simple way to filter directly at `opts` definition, it is not elegant :-)

Comment: @Peter Krauss, you could certainly apply the `Option to String` transformation to `opts`, as shown in the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting to List first:

```
val a :: b :: _ = "Hello,Bye,etc".split(',').toList
```